# Third node cannot join Galera cluster after mariadb update

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I tried to deal with this issue for three days now, but unfortunately without success.

I have a Galera cluster (Node1 - donor, Node2 - joiner, Node3 - arbitrator) which was working flawlessly until I decided to update mariadb package.

Details: Node1 and Node2 are physical servers so I cannot revert a snapshot or similar, Node3 is VM and all of them are running Debian 9.

The first issue occurred right after doing the update (apt upgrade) and the error that I got was:

```
2018-08-10 12:01:53 139701369419520 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '192.168.1.7' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '48395'  '' : 2
2018-08-10 12:01:53 139701369419520 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read uuid:seqno and wsrep_gtid_domain_id from joiner script.
2018-08-10 12:01:53 139712303212736 [ERROR] WSREP: SST failed: 2 (No such file or directory)
2018-08-10 12:01:53 139712303212736 [ERROR] Aborting
2018-08-10 12:01:53 139701377812224 [Warning] WSREP: 0.0 (Node1): State transfer to 1.0 (Node2) failed: -22 (Invalid argument)
2018-08-10 12:01:53 139701377812224 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():737: Will never receive state. Need to abort.
mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Failed to start MariaDB 10.2.16 database server.
mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

The cluster is still alive and keeping quorum with 2 nodes (Node1 and Node3). A lot of googling and different ideas, including purge of all mariadb packages and:

If I run a clean installation of mysql on the server, without syncing set up, it starts fine. In case I enable the syncing, I get the same error as before. If, after this I want to start mysql again without syncing, I get the following error:

```
2018-08-10 11:57:01 140195030619904 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-08-10 11:57:01 140195030619904 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open '/var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
2018-08-10 11:57:01 140262652463296 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-08-10 11:57:01 140262652463296 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2018-08-10 11:57:01 140262652463296 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2018-08-10 11:57:01 140262652463296 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start MariaDB 10.2.16 database server.
mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

My config from /etc/mysql/my.cnf is:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

default-character-set   = utf8mb4

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking

skip-name-resolve
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
character-set-server    = utf8mb4

event_scheduler     = 1
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  = 1
max_seeks_for_key   = 18446744073709551615
max_write_lock_count    = 18446744073709551615

plugin-load         = sql_errlog.so
sql_error_log_rotate        = 1
sql_error_log_rotations     = 9
sql_error_log_size_limit    = 1M
sql_error_log_rate      = 1
sql_error_log_filename      = sql_errors.log

max_connections     = 1000
connect_timeout     = 10
wait_timeout        = 28800
max_allowed_packet  = 64M

thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size    = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M

myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 128M
table_open_cache    = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
query_cache_limit       = 128K
query_cache_size        = 0
query_cache_type        = OFF
log_warnings        = 2
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
innodb_log_file_size    = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 60G
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_file_format = Barracuda

[galera]

wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.1.6,192.168.1.7,192.168.1.8 # Node1, Node2, Node3 (arbitrator)

wsrep_cluster_name="galera_cluster"
wsrep_node_name='Node2'
wsrep_node_address="192.168.1.7"
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth=galera_sst:secret
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size = 10G"

binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2

innodb_doublewrite=1
wsrep_retry_autocommit=3

[sst]
compressor="gzip"
decompressor="gzip -dc"

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Logs on Node1 or Node3 are not showing anything useful.